# Itunes Non-public API usage: How to find selectors?

Tags: ios, xcode, api, app-store-connect, selector

After I upload the binary through Xcode, an email from Itunes arrives saying my App has one or more issues, and describing:

```
        Non-public API usage:

            The app references non-public selectors in MY APP:   _addRecorder:,
            _playbackEvents:atPlaybackRate:messageWhenDone:withSelector:,
            _removeRecorder:, 
            terminateWithSuccess
```

I do not call those selectors anywhere in my code, I've searched all of them and haven't found anything. Maybe one of the app's linked libraries is calling those selectors but I can't find anything.

I've tried searching with Appscanner , but it's old and not working. 
Also added symbolic breakpoints, but those selectors are just called by `UIApplication`

Any other clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally founded the  problematic framework with the simple grep command:

```
grep -R '_addRecorder:' *
```

Did the magic.